# PostgreSQL log_min_messages not working?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to debug my SQL code and therefore I need some logging messages. However, setting `log_min_messages` and `client_min_messages` to level `NOTICE` does not work as expected:

```
SET log_min_messages = 'NOTICE';
SET client_min_messages = 'NOTICE';
```

The function I am using:

```
CREATE FUNCTION on_insert_or_update_shop_offer()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Test trigger';
    RETURN new;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER shop_offer_insert_or_update_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON shop_offer
FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE on_insert_or_update_shop_offer();
```

I have tested it by calling `RAISE EXCEPTION 'Test trigger';` which appears as intended, but I am not getting `NOTICE` level messages.

Comment: What are you using to run the insert? Where are you looking for the messages?

Comment: @NickBarnes Not sure about the first question but I am using jOOQ, a Java library, to access the database. The insert works though. I am looking for the messages in my Eclipse Console (stdout). I assumed that those messages will be displayed there since `EXCEPTION` gets displayed there.

Comment: stdout/stderr is probably showing you the corresponding Java exception, and for a `NOTICE` or `WARNING`, there isn't one. You should be able to retrieve the messages yourself via `Statement.getWarnings()`. If you set `log_min_messages`, they'll also be in the server log.

Answer (score 2):

ALTER DATABASE dbname SET log_min_messages TO notice;